# How to initialize nested 2D int array (or array of pointers to int[]?) with arrays of different length in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, compile-time

I'm trying to do such init in first line and then peek whats inside first 5 sub-arrays:

```
    int * v [] = {new int[20001], new int[10001], new int[5001], new int[2501], new int[1251], new int[626], new int[313], new int[157], new int[79], new int[40], new int[20], new int[10], new int[5], new int[3], new int[2]};
    
    int ind_array = 15;
    int ind_element = 1;
    while (ind_array-- > 10)
            cout << ind_array << "[" << ind_element << "] = " << v[ind_array][ind_element] << endl;
```

This seem to compile, but I can't see elements that I expect (zeros): for every array when ind_element = 0 or = 1 it returns me some (overflow) value (-1094795586) and when ind_element >= 2 crashes with "==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer...".

How can I initialize such structure and how can I access its elements?

Comment: How about using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @MikeCAT Too slow.

Comment: `new` as used here allocates memory but does not initialize it to any particular value. `v[14]` only has two elements so trying to access `v[14][2]` can result in your error.

Comment: You aren't initializing the new values.  use `new int[N]{};`

Comment: @Rustam A. Source on that please. `vector` is one of the most optimised containers in existance and should provide comparable performance to a (heap allocated) standard C array. If it doesn't thats a compiler/std library bug and you should file it with your vendor

Comment: "Too slow"? FUD. Vector does new that you did explicitly and vector does initialize elements that you incorrectly expected your new to do as well. So if you add missing {} suggested by doug then it is unlikely that you manage to observe any performance differences.

Comment: Normally I help newbies with everything. But there is a hard rule in C++: Do not use raw pointers for owned memory. Do not use new. In this context, the only viable solution is ````std::vector```` or ````std::array````. Everything else what you do here is error prone and much slower than using STL container. Simply do not go into this direction.

Comment: @ÖöTiib, you and others right in most of the things you said including performance. Still my need is somewhat marginal: I'm interested in c++ because I find competitive programming entertaining and my python sometimes fails to fit tight limits. And raw int[] gives a nice boost even over vector - so I want to know how to use it - this init with 'new' keyword I collected from different answers on SO since I couldn't find such non-square aray init on cppreference.com and cplusplus.com (thought now I start to think, maybe I should have looked on c-resources, not c++).

Comment: Question is answered thank you all! Should I close it somehow? Or just leave it as it is?